# combining rows into one with groupby in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

[dataframe picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D4Tp.png)

i have a data frame with columns 'Time', 'District' and 'Count'. 'Time' currently has values of time on a 24-hour clock by minute and I would like to group it so that it is separated by time of day (ie morning, midday, night) rather than by minute. I have been able to group by hour using this documentation:

df.groupby([df['Time'].str[0:2]]).agg({'Count':'sum'})

I would ideally be able to group by time of day so that all rows with time from say, 00:01 - 06:00 say 'Morning' and have the 'Count' column have the sum of all row instances in a given District. For instance, if there is a count of 100 in the District Bayview from 00:01 - 06:00, the row would read: Morning, Bayview, 100.

However, I am trying to not aggregate on any value (if possible) as it changes the index / columns and I would like to plot it on a Folium map.

Comment: Please post the df sample as text, not as an image.

Comment: Maybe you can read this first [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]